# Recurrence Relation for Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have worked out a few successive derivations of Bayes' Theorem...

$\Pr(W) = \Pr(W)$
$\Pr(W\ |\ C_1)\ =\ \frac{\Pr(C_1\ |\ W)\Pr(W)}{\Pr(C_1)}$
$\Pr(W\ |\ (C_1\ \cap\ C_2))\ =\ \frac{\Pr(C_2\ |\ (W\ \cap\ C_1))\Pr(W\ |\ C_1)}{\Pr(C_2\ |\ C_1)}$
$\Pr(W\ |\ (C_1\ \cap\ C_2\ \cap\ C_3)) = \frac{\Pr(C_3\ |\ (W\ \cap\ C_1\ \cap\ C_2))\Pr(W\ |\ (C_1\ \cap\ C_2))}{\Pr(C_3\ |\ (C_1\ \cap\ C_2))}$

I think the pattern is $\Pr(W\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} C_i)\ =\ \frac{\Pr(C_{n - 1}\ |\ (W\ \cap\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i))\Pr(W\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i)}{\Pr(C_{n - 1}\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i)}$.  I have intuition that this should be interpretable as a recurrence relation.  As far as I can tell, $\Pr(W\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} C_i)$ is playing the role of $a_n$, and $\Pr(W\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i)$ is playing the role of $a_{n - 1}$.  However, it is less clear what to do with the other factors.  Should I leave them as probabilities, yielding $a_n =\ \frac{\Pr(C_{n - 1}\ |\ (W\ \cap\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i))}{\Pr(C_{n - 1}\ |\ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} C_i)} a_{n - 1}$, or is there some transformation I need to apply to the coefficient as well?  Or should I leave everything in probability notation?  The coefficient is certainly not constant in this form, yet I believe the solution should be simple (probably related to Bayesean updating formulas).  How can I massage this into an analytically solvable form?

Answer (score 2):

The Bayes' theorem says:
$$\mathbb{P}(W |\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i ) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(W \cap\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )}{\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )} \tag{1}$$
Given the sets $(C_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}_+} \subset \Omega$ , we define the functions $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N_+}$  as follows
$$
\begin{align}
  a_n\colon \Omega & \mapsto [0,1] \hspace{5cm} \text{for }n \in \mathbb{N_+}\\[-1ex]  
  A & \longmapsto a_n(A) :=\mathbb{P}(A |\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )
\end{align}
$$

Then from $(1)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
a_n(W)&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W \cap\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )}{\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )}\\ &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W\cap C_n \cap\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )}{\mathbb{P}(C_n \cap \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W\cap C_n |\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )\cdot\mathbb{P}( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )}{\mathbb{P}(C_n |\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )\cdot\mathbb{P}( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W\cap C_n |\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )}{\mathbb{P}(C_n |\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i )} \\
\color{red}{a_n(W)}&\color{red}{= \frac{a_{n-1}(W \cap C_n)}{a_{n-1}(C_n)}} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

I think that $(2)$ is the best recurrence relation that we can have.

Comment: I guess the equation in red is not quite a recurrence relation but a functional equation since the inputs differ, probably with little hope of being solved or approached?

Comment: @user10478 as I wrote in the last phrase, I believe $(2)$ is the best thing that we can have